# How can I navigate into components on react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've fletched a list of items and rendered it into my app.
Its the first page of the app.
The thing that I want to do is:
Make each of the items "touchable", and when you touch it, you open a component filled with objects from a second fetch requisition.

I am new to react native, do you know if I have to use a lib or something to do it?

Comment: Rather showing that in a component directly , you can use navigation to move to a screen by where you can show that data ! For navigation , you can use react navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer your questions one by one.

**Make each of the items "touchable"**
Wrap your components with `TouchableOpacity` which you can import from react native like this `import {TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";`

**when you touch it, you open a component filled with objects**
You need to implement `onPress` method there and also react navigation to load other components.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("newScreenName")}>
    <MyCustomComponent>
      ...
    </MyCustomComponent>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and creating screen will be like this :

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import Screen1 from "./Screen1";
import Screen2 from "./Screen2";
...
const customStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    newScreenName: {
      screen: Screen1
    },
    newScreenName1: {
      screen: Screen2
    }
  },
  {}
);
```

check [API](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html) & [Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html) here 
Also, Please check this [example](https://github.com/navneet-kumar/MyClinic/tree/master) for more details

Comment: You definitely do not need NativeBase to achieve what OP wants. I'd suggest abstaining from libraries like these until you understand how to do it without. A small personal anecdote, I've had issues with NativeBase breaking changes between updates and the developer being less than willing to fix it ("just use the older version", which was incompatible with the new React Native version). Very unprofessional, and I won't be using them again.

Comment: Make sense, yes it is difficult some times to understand them. i have changed the link to one of my learning project have a look.